Mentioning owning a business on an interview
I'm approaching the idea of starting an IT business. I think, for the first period (let's say about a year) I won't have any income, but expenses. Thus, I would like to be an employee of another IT company in the meantime.
It doesn't seem to be a problem as is, as my field/market/product would not collide with the company I would like to work for.
My question is, should I disclose to this company that I'm about to open mine? If it's possible, I wouldn't.

Please state your country. It is perfectly normal where I live for example, that the employer has to agree to you opening a business. Does your contract state anything like that?

It's Hungary. I haven't seen the contract yet.

Similar question

How do I ask permission to setup my own business without coming across 'unserious' to my employer?

How would you have no income and only expenses? Do you plan on working for free? You may have expenses that exceed your income but I don't understand how you would have no income?

@joeqwerty: "How would you have no income and only expenses?" - it doesn't seem unusual for new businesses to take a while to go from an idea/prototype to an actually marketable product.

@joeqwerty, indeed that's the case.

@nvoigt may I ask what country that is? That concept seems insane to me (which means it's almost certainly just a discrepancy between accepted cultural norms :D )

Based on tags ... I might guess Germany?

@Brondahl Yes, Germany has such rules. Your employer has certain rights based on the expectation that you work for them. That covers things such as being able to deny separate work if it would significantly affect your performance (e.g. because you are tired from managing your business) or there would be a conflict of interest.

So, of course, you would quit your IT job once your own business takes off.
No, don't mention that.

that's contingent on your regular employer not having any IP or conflict of interest policies that mandate any disclosure of other jobs or side hustles.

Thank you @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight, I'll check their contract regarding this.

So it's okay to screw the company?  Wow.  This is why we can't have nice things.  Everyone is only out for themselves, and we all suffer as a result.

@JohnGordon So it's okay to screw the company? Yes, it is. As the company will tell you when it fires you - "It's not personal, it's just business."

@JohnGordon it's okay, companies aren't people

@JohnGordon A company screwed me last year without any warning. A quick chat to tell me I was no longer needed and told to leave the building.

@camden_kid I'm sure that happens all the time, and that's unfortunate.  But that doesn't mean its ok to not tell the company that you will only be staying for a year.  Two wrongs don't make a right.

@JohnGordon OP doesn't know they will be staying for a year. They are hedging their bets. Companies do that too. It's all part of the dance.

@JohnGordon It depends... Most companies lost any right to complaining about "No employee loyalty" When they stopped showing loyalty to their employees.. There are exceptions, but they exist in the minority.

That being said, if OPs IT business is a direct competitor to their employer, then they might be in violation of a no compete clause. unless employment contract starts after September 2024 (When non competes were banned for regular working Joes, finally)... US laws tend to not be retroactive, so uncertain about contracts entered before that date.

@camden_kid They seem pretty certain about starting their business.  So yes, I would say they know they will leave after a year, or at a minimum it is a strong possibility.  And I believe it is wrong not to disclose that.

I should have read the tags... Welp, my comment applies for this exact question if the q is US based...

@Questor - What you describe isn’t law in every state within the US, nor can it be law in every state in the country, very few things become federal laws with the constitution becoming involved. As much as employers have become disloyal to employees, employees, have become increasingly disloyal to companies.

The ban on no compete articles in employment contracts for average joes is a federal law that went into effect on September 2024... Before that, yes it depends on the state you were in.

Assuming you haven't started the company yet.

My question is, should I disclose to this company that I'm about to
open mine?

Telling them your plan: I am going to quit in a year, no matter the reason, is not a good thing to say in the hiring process. You are telling them the chances of me providing more benefit than cost have just gone down significantly.
Now once you have the job, the question is when do you tell them? That depends on what the employment documents say. They may need to know about any outside employment. Others won't care unless you will be stealing their customers, or their resources.
Once you start the company do nothing related to your new company while on the clock with your employer. Don't answer a call. Don't check a website. Don't read an email. Don't use your employers phone or computer for your company business.
After you do tell your employer, and they are OK with it, never mention it to any of their customers or your co-workers.

Thank you, this looks crucial to follow.

I have a different take on it.  There are two sides to it.
As already mentioned, if you tell your prospective employer that you have divided attention and loyalty.  And that you want to leave in an year, you probably wont get the job.
The flip side is that many employment contracts stipulate that

Moonlighting is not allowed
Any inventions while in employment (even if made outside working hours and off-premises) belong to the company.

By not telling the employer, you run the risk of getting fired for violating the contract and / or losing your IP in your personal work.

Make sure that the contract does not have these clauses.
If it does have these clauses

Then don't tell anyone at work, not even a fellow employee about it.
If an invention is involved then prepare it before commencing employment.




"Any inventions while in employment (even if made outside working hours and off-premises) belong to the company." At least in the UK, a clause this broad is null and void.

@PhilipKendall: Company lawyers are usually careful to craft this so it will pass muster, for example by saying that only inventions within the company's scope of business are claimed, and then having policies which further died what they do and don't consider conflicts of interest. They are very aware that they may have to defend it in court. This is why lawyers get the big bucks.

@PhilipKendall In the U.S. that is a common condition for technical employment, notably where the company's primary asset or goods/services for sale are intangible.

@JBH Even in the US, that is way too restrictive (though you need to be careful). Also, if it is a large company, fighting them would be cost-prohibitive (even if you would technically win).

usa Even if it did collide, from a legal standpoint, doesn't matter anymore as noncompete are now illegal (for the average Joe Schmoe). So long as you aren't hired on as a senior executive with decision making authority with a salary greater than 154K and a golden parachute (that comes with such positions) you are legally ok on that front.
Should you tell?
I have a couple thoughts on this subject.

if I tell, I probably won't get the job, and its possible my IT business never takes off, as most startups fail within the first few years without turning a profit. So really, at this point in time its more like an expensive hobby.

Most employers have lost any right to employee loyalty as they haven't shown any loyalty to their employees. Layoffs after a major project finishes to increase profits for stockholders? If they don't show any loyalty to me, why should I show it to them. (Note this thought only applies to most companies, there are exceptions. Some companies never have layoffs and retrain all employees made redundant due to innovation. If the company that you are applying for is one of these rare gems, than this thought doesn't apply.)

Would I hire someone that says they plan on leaving in a year? Nope... It takes about 3 months to get someone trained up on our system, and another 6 months until they hit the break even point (Where the cost of hiring/training has been paid off). I want someone to come and work for me for at least 2-3 years (preferably until retirement). As hiring people is expensive, time consuming, and recent hires (< 1 year) are the biggest source of costly mistakes.


In summary, I wouldn't tell them.
It will take longer than you think to get your business up and profitable enough to pay the bills (if it ever does). If this company was already making you money, I would tell them. If you knew for sure that you would be leaving them in a year to run your company, I would tell them. But it isn't making anything right now, and you don't know when this company of yours is going to take off.
